# how to remove "downloading" or 0% complete torrents in rtorrent using bash script?

Tags: bash, shell-script, bittorrent, rtorrent

I have 10K torrents and 7K of them are going too slow. I would like to remove them but the rutorrent and rtorrent interface is unusably slow. I noticed that the info about rtorrent is kept in `.session` folder but i can't figure out how to see the status of the torrent, meaning how much % is completed.

so is there a way for a bash script to see how much of the torrent is downloaded? i would prefer a performance critical way.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you also want to get rid of the partial data...

```
rtcontrol --from-view incomplete // --cull
```

→ https://code.google.com/p/pyroscope/wiki/InstallFromSource